# How to get latest value from kafka 1.1.0 using KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic 'meta_connection' in which key is 'machine' and value is 'machine's coneection info'. I want to get the latest connection info of a given
machine from this topic when required. Is this possible with KTable? if yes please give an example. I am using kafka 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is a pub/sub system, and as such data is delivered immediately to any subscriber. A KTable is simply an interpretation of the latest value per key from a Kafka topic. The "table" can be materialized in to a [`ReadOnlyKeyValueStore`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.html)and then queried using Kafka Streams' [Interactive Query feature](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html), which would provide you with a query-able interface.

There's a good explanation of interactive queries [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app) with links to example codes on github.